# Is an arbitrary union of a chain of countable sets countable?

Tags: set-theory

> Let $C$ be a chain of countable sets, i.e. $\forall S, T \in C: S \subseteq T \lor T \subseteq S$, and that every $S \in C$ is countable.
>
> Then, is $\bigcup C := \{ t \mid \exists S \in C: t \in S\}$ countable?

The answer is no, and a counter-example is $C = \omega_1$, the first uncountable cardinal/ordinal.

Is there a more elementary example that doesn't involve, say, cardinals and ordinals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wish to assume choice, then you have no way around $\omega_1$. The reason being that any chain has a well-ordered cofinal subset, and thus if all the members of the chain are countable that subset has to be countable or of type $\omega_1$. In the former case the union of the chain is countable, and in the latter it will be of size $\aleph_1$.

But what happens without assuming the axiom of choice? Well. It is consistent that $\Bbb R$ is a countable union of countable sets, or that you have a Russell set, that is a countable union of pairwise disjoint pairs that admit no choice function.

In any such case, you have $\{A_n\mid n<\omega\}$ as a countable family of countable sets (in the Russell set case, finite), then defining $B_n=\bigcup_{k<n}A_n$ gives you that $\{B_n\mid n<\omega\}$ is a countable chain of countable sets whose union is uncountable.

Comment: Doesn't my counter-example hold in ZF?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a **countable** chain.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Early morning... :P

Comment: @Kenny: Yes, you're right. I've edited to reflect that.

Comment: Why is $\omega_1$ a union of a countable chain?

Comment: @Kenny: It is pretty much by definition.

Comment: Also, isn't a countable union of countable sets countable under ZFC?

Comment: @Kenny: Yes, I'm not sure which bothers you? The fact that I say that a chain of countable sets will have either a countable cofinal subset, in which case its union is countable, or a cofinal subset of type $\omega_1$ in which case its union must have a cardinality of $\omega_1$, or is it something else?

Comment: I see. I parsed your sentence wrongly. You said: if all the members of the chain are countable [(that subset has to be countable, and you resort to a countable union of countable sets), or (ω1).] I thought you said: if all the members of the chain are countable [that subset has to be countable, and you resort to (a countable union of countable sets, or ω1).]

Comment: i.e. I thought you mean ω1 is a countable union of countable sets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution working with the set $\mathbb R$.

First obtain a well-order $<$ for $\mathbb R$.

Consider the set $X = \{ x |\hspace{0.1cm} (-\infty,x] \text{ is not countable }\}$, where the intervals are taken in the well-order.

If $X$ is empty we can let our chain be $\{ (-\infty,x] \hspace{0.1cm}| x \in \mathbb R)$.

If $X$ is not empty let $x$ be the minimum element.

We will let our chain be $\{ (-\infty,y]\hspace{0.1cm} | y<x )$.

every element of the chain is countable, but the union is not, as every element of $(-\infty,x]$ except for $x$ is in the union, and $(-\infty,x]$ is not.

Comment: When you write $(-\infty,x]$, that seems that you mean the well-order, since in the standard order, these are all uncountable. In either case, starting with a well-order, you are pretty much rolling yourself into the ordinals.

Comment: Yes, I added that clarification. Oh OK, although this is more friendly at least for me since I don't remember all of the stuff from my ordinal class, but I remember the well-ordering. Thank you for the help!