# Does a total or well ordering has a countable cofinal

Tags: logic, set-theory, order-theory, axiom-of-choice, well-orders

I read a post sometime earlier asking about the cardinality of total ordering on a set, which I forgot about the detail but led me to this question.

> For a total/well-ordered set $A$ does there exist a cofinal such that it is countable? If not, what is a counterexample?

My intuition is to use Zorn's lemma, which leads to the problem that [the union of a chain of countable sets is not necessarily countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867719/is-an-arbitrary-union-of-a-chain-of-countable-sets-countable), but I do not completely understand the answer. Anyway, if we assume AC or perhaps even GCH, can we get any conclusion about the cardinality of the cofinal?

Comment: Depends on the ordering… sometimes yes and sometimes no.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yeah sorry I fixed my question, what do you think about providing a counterexample then?

Comment: The first uncountable ordinal. The size of the smallest cofinal subset is called the cofinality and the cofinality of an ordinal/well-ordered set can be any regular cardinal.

Comment: So the example is $\omega_1$ ... see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/956779/an-easy-to-understand-definition-of-omega-1